# Multiple descendants types linq

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

I sometimes do this:

```
XElement.Descendants("mynodename");
```

is there a way to do something like this"

```
XElement.Descendants("mynodename or myothernodename");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not in one method call - but you can use:

```
element.Descendants()
       .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "mynodename" 
                   || x.Name.LocalName == "myothernodename")
```

Answer (score 3):

Or,

```
XElement.Descendants("mynodename")
  .Union(XElement.Descendants("myothernodename"));
```

Which would sort them by type, then in order of appearance...