# How to add OR condition in LINQ while querying XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Problem: return all records `where` `Jon Doe` `=<bus_contact>` **OR** `<bus_sponsor>`.

Current code returns record 1, so what modifications are required to return records 1 and 2 using just one query?.

XML

```
<root>
  <row>
    <project_id>1</project_id>
    <project_name>Name1</project_name>
    <bus_contact>Jon Doe</bus_contact>
    <bus_sponsor>Bruce Wayne</bus_sponsor>
  </row>
  <row>
    <project_id>2</project_id>
    <project_name>Name2</project_name>
    <bus_contact>Peter Parker</bus_contact>
    <bus_sponsor>Jon Doe</bus_sponsor>
  </row>
</root>
```

C#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        XElement main = XElement.Load ("master_list.xml");

        var results = main.Descendants ("row")
            .Descendants ("bus_contact")
            .Where (e => e.Value == "Jon Doe")
            .Select (e => e.Parent)               
            .Select (e => new {
                project_id = e.Descendants ("project_id").FirstOrDefault ().Value,
                project_name = e.Descendants ("project_name").FirstOrDefault ().Value
            });

        foreach (var result in results)
            Console.WriteLine ("{0}, {1}", result.project_id, result.project_name);
        Console.ReadLine ();
    }
}
```

**Edit** : This is not exactly the same problem as pointed out in the possible duplicate link. Yes, it partially refers to that but as a beginner getting an answer with appropriate context, which the accepted answer provides, is quite helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple descendants types linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059488/multiple-descendants-types-linq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `||` in combination with `Any`, like this:

```
var results = main.Descendants("row")
    .Where(r =>
        r.Descendants("bus_contact").Any(c => c.Value == "Jon Doe")
    ||  r.Descendants("bus_sponsor").Any(c => c.Value == "Jon Doe")
    );
```

Using `Any` lets you query by a condition on a child, without actually descending to the child level. This eliminated necessity to climb the tree back by selecting `Parent`.

Comment: Awesome. thanks!!! Answer will accepted as soon as the time limit is over.

Answer (score 1):

If each `row` element has only one subelement item of each kind (`bus_contact`, `bus_sponsor`, etc.) you can simplify the whole query by using [`Element`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of `Descendants`

```
var results =
    main.Descendants ("row")
    .Where (r => r.Element("bus_contact").Value == "Jon Doe"
              || r.Element("bus_contact").Value == "Jon Doe")
    .Select (r => new {
        project_id = r.Element("project_id").Value,
        project_name = r.Element("project_name").Value
    });
```

Comment: @cyboashu not added to answer but if `row` tag are the sole children of `root` you could also replace `Descendants` by `Elements` (plural)